# Regex - Searching for a string after nth comma in CSV file

Tags: regex, powershell, notepad++

I inherited a project at the office that I can't quite seem to find the answer to. I am trying to write a Powershell script using Regex to replace text in specific field of a multi-line comma separated CSV file, but the text I am replacing could exist in other fields.

For example, in the following data:

```
Smith,Robert,W,11111 N 400 W,Some City,Some State,Some Zip
```

I need to replace `W` in the fourth column with `West`, but I don't want the `W` in the third column (or other columns) to be changed. At the very least, I could just have it search for any match after the nth comma since the fields following the street address are mostly numeric, but ideally, it'd be nice to only search the specific column in case there would be matching text elsewhere in the future.

I have found some tips and Regex scripts that seem to get me close, but am struggling get it to work testing it with Notepad++. Some scripts are searching everything up to the nth comma, some seemed to be searching backwards from the end of the line (which won't work because there are text fields with commas). The closest I have gotten in the PowerShell script so far is:

```
-replace('^(?:[^,]*\,){3}([^,]*)\bW\b', 'West')
```

But this replaces the `W` and everything before it with `West`.

It's likely that there is even a better way to do this, but I've already spent more time on this than I anticipated. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Whats the reason behind doing this with regex instead of using a CSV parser?

Comment: Does the CSV file have column headers?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, the file comes from a hosted system via SFTP and is then imported on a schedule into software on one of our servers. I could actually parse it using our SQL server, but I want as few moving parts as possible.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, yes it does.

Comment: Moving parts? PowerShell comes with a built-in Csv parser, but if you wanna resolve this via regex I can't do other thing than shrug

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, as mentioned in my original post, I am using Regex within Powershell. And also as mentioned in my original post, I stated that there's likely a better way to do it, which is why I'm reaching out for help. Shrugs aren't helping anyone.

Comment: and i'm always willing to help but you haven't provided an actual example of how the csv looks like, including headers and your first approach at resolving the problem was with regex when you seem to be aware that CSV is structured data and regex is not the right approach when dealing with structured data.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I provided as much info as I thought was needed, including pointing out that I was using Regex in a PowerShell script. The info was all right there minus the headers (which in the end turned out to be irrelevant). If more info was needed for you to be able to help, why not simply ask for more info instead of the snide replies? Others were able to assist without further info.

Comment: Whatever answer you use, I would recommend to add `\n` into the negated class for excluding newlines as well. Else in multiline input [**this** can happen (regex101 demo)](https://regex101.com/r/fQ2EqI/1).

Answer (score 2):

Fairly straightforward. The regex you tried was very close.
Leading up to the `W` in the fourth column just has to be written back along with West
in the replacement.

This is a portable solution.

```
@"(?m)^((?:[^,]*,){3}[^,]*?)\bW\b"
```

Replace `$1West`

https://regex101.com/r/zLlP7L/1

```
(?m)
^
(                             # (1 start)
   (?: [^,]* , ){3}
   [^,]*? 
)                             # (1 end)
\b W \b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookbehind to do an assertion without matching those content (note that `,` doesn't need to be escaped):

```
(?m)               # (Make '^' means the start of a line)
(?<=               # Match something preceded by
  ^(?:[^,]*,){3}   # 3 columns at the start of line
  [^,]*            # then 0 or more non-comma characters,
)                  # in which "something" means
\bW\b              # a 'W' with no adjacent word characters.
```

Assuming `$string` is your input, here's a short Powershell snippet:

<sub>(Disclaimer: I don't really know Powershell.)</sub>

```
$result = $string -replace '(?m)(?<=^(?:[^,]*,){3}[^,]*)\bW\b', 'West'
```

Note that Powershell has [built-in support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) for parsing CSV files. You might want to use that instead to avoid any potential problems.

Try it [on tio.run](https://tio.run/##pY69CsIwFEb3PMUdhLSSQkUnsbTg7mCHgNZCKxcbSE1IbikiPnv8qT6B33SW73CsGdH5DrUOYebJqesFMig4K3tFndibFh0JKRbvwQ5WaQpSlKZH2Cq6TVRSQzjhQdl/rrxgM4d@0PSq@PUkDq1uzgg8yvs4yjdZHeXrYy1OcxHfl48PxVUrq5YL4BI9ccZGpwgTM5AdCL7SEJ4).

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HAt0tw/2).

Comment: Does Powershell use any kind of standards when parsing csv ? Is it compatible with Excel ?

Comment: @sln I'm not sure; I don't know Powershell that much.

Comment: Ok, my experience with Excel is that it's very finiky and unforgiving when it comes to csv parsing

Comment: @sln, PowerShell's [CSV parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) is strictly type-agnostic and reports all column values as-is, as _strings_.

Comment: @mklement0 - `character-separated value (CSV) file`. Objects, objects, objects. The truth is MS is weak in parsing and Standards. Couldn't parse it's way out of a wet paper bag. Can't do a thing with those objects. I got so sick of all these csv, no standards baloney, I got an app that does it all with csv just to massage and repair input, compensate across the board.  https://regexformat.com/scrn8/CsvConv.jpg

Comment: @sln, its _comma_-separated values, and the values are inherently untyped, and how to interpret them is up to each consumer. I was contrasting PowerShell's all-values-are-strings parsing with the _heuristics_ employed by Excel with respect to _guessing_ data types, which can situationally either be helpful or destructive. As far as I know, PowerShell's parsing complies with the - common, but non-prescriptive - format documented in [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).

Comment: @mklement0 - I'm glad you posted a link to something you never read `Creates table-like custom objects from the items in a character-separated value (CSV) file.` Perhaps you should not claim to be whatever you claim to be. https://regexformat.com/scrn8/CsvConv.jpg

Comment: @sln: In case you're referring to the fact that PowerShell parses CSV files into _objects_ whose _properties_ reflect the CSV column values: that is incidental to the point that I was making. I have no idea how your screenshot relates to what I said. Given your tone, I think this conversation has run its course.

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:[^,]*\,){3}[^,]*?\KW`
- Replace with: `West`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(?:         # non capture group
    [^,]*       # 0 or more any character that is not a comma
    ,           # a comma
){3}        # end group, must appear 3 times
[^,]*?      # 0 or more any character that is not a comma, not greedy
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
W           # letter W
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: ^(?:[^,]*\,){9}[^,]*?\K\bW\b works perfectly in Notepad++, but Powershell returns an InvalidRegularExpression

Comment: I guess it doesn't support è\Kè. You could use: `^((?:[^,]*\,){3}[^,]*?)W` and replace with `$1West`

Answer (score 0):

I would in these kind of situations usually write regexes that are a bit verbose, but that certainly work.

In this case, I would do something like this:

`-replace('^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)\bW\b,', '\1,\2,\3,\4West,')`

Although I am not sure how regexes work in powershell, sometimes you should use `$1`,`$2`,... or even `%1`,`%2`,... but I believe `\1`,`\2`,... is most common.

Explanation/breakdown:

- `^`: match start of line
- `([^,]*)` Match anything that is not a comma. This will be our first capture group, `\1`
- `,` Match a literal comma
- `([^,]*),([^,]*),` Two more capture groups without commas, for `\2` and `\3`.
- `([^,]*)\bW\b,` Match something without commas in the capture group `\4`, and then a `W`, and then a comma.

Replace with:
`\1,\2,\3,\4West`
where we use our capture groups and then west.